# $timeout.flush during protractor test

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-ngmock

My website has an app-wide session timeout that is set as soon as the page loads. When testing in protractor, I would like to call **ngMocks**'s `$timeout.flush()` to kill the timeout, but I have not figured out how to get a handle on the `$timeout` service in the **ngMock** module from within **Protractor**.

Is this possible? Has anyone else tried this approach to circumvent the timeout issue in protractor?